# Not able to connect to eclipse market place in eclipse version 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I am trying to connect to connect to eclipse marketplace in eclipse IDE. I am getting following error:

### Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace

Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot resolve host

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unknown Host: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Unknown Host: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
server.proxy.org
Cannot resolve host
This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.##

I am trying to make it work long time. If there is any solution please provide me with same.

I have tried all the solutions on available on internet:

1. change provider in windows->preference->Genaral->Network Connections to active, native, manual
2. I have also checked proxy setting in windos->settings->proxy tab. I don't find any proxy connections.
3. I have also tried to turn off firewall but it didn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you are using an outdated Eclipse version and the path of your Eclipse installation directory contains spaces, this is a bug that have been fixed some time ago. In this case, please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: @howlger my eclipse versio is 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Comment: You are two releases behind. Does upgrading fix your issue? The [status of the Eclipse servers are tracked here](https://status.eclipse.org/).